# Is there a way to make a drop down menu like this?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, menu

Is there anyone that know how to make a drop down menu like this?

[image]

I would put it in this if it was me:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //in here
}
```

Comment: Of course it is possible, but it's ugly and I wouldn't call it a dropdown myself, although it is technically speaking very close to a "dropdown". where and how you put it is your business, not ours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , You can use `ListBox` control.

**OR**

You can use `ComboBox` Control by setting the `DropDownStyle` property to  `Simple`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to search for a String from ListBox and Select the Item if it is matching with it

```
You need to have a TextBox to receive the Serach String as input.
```

[image]

You need to handle the TextBox Key_Down Event handler to start searching.

**Note:** In below code i have started searching when user enters `ENTER` key after entering the input search string.

Try This:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            var itemSearched = textBox1.Text;
            int itemCount = 0;
            foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                if (item.ToString().IndexOf(itemSearched,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)!=-1)
                {
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex = itemCount;
                    break;
                }

                itemCount++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know so how text inside match the word your typing?

Comment: You mean in `Combobox`?

Comment: No the ListBox. That really what i need :)

Comment: Thanks that did some of the job :) Marked as awnser :) I can do the rest myself

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need AutoCompleteBox from WPFToolkit.
You can set it up from NuGet with following command:

```
PM> Install-Package WPFToolkit
```

Here is the code snippet for using this control:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="InputBox" Margin="0,77,0,159"/>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InputBox.ItemsSource = new List<string>
            { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };
        }
    }
}
```